# Stream APIを使って日付をソートしたい。

Tags: java8

複数のオブジェクトを保有しているList変数(students)を使って日付をキーにそれぞれのオブジェクトにソートをかけたいのですが下記のようなコードだと上手くいきません。どう修正したらよろしいでしょうか。
JSONのレスポンスは下のような形となります
[{"id":24,"name":"田中","score":"30","date":1388673900000},{"id":30,"name":"安藤","score":"48","date":1388760300000}]

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8011/student?    userId=00002", Student[].class));
Stream<Student> studentsSort = students.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getDate));
```

Comment: 上手くいかない、という状況をもう少し具体的に記載すると良いかも知れません。例えば、〜というメッセージのコンパイルエラーが出る、実行すると〜という例外が出る、実行はできるが想定通りのソート結果にならない、など。

Comment: なぜListをソートするだけなのにStreamを使いたいんでしょうか。[Collections#sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-)ではだめでしょうか。

Comment: springの起動をしなおしてみると上手くいきました。複数回起動していたのが原因だと思います。

Comment: streamAPIはJava8からの機能でソートするのが得意であると知ったからです。Java8を使っているのでせっかくなのでspanAPIを使ってみたいと思いました。